# Getting CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT code on checking file existence

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am using the following code to check the file existence on http sever.
but I am getting `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT` code. Can anyone tell me how to check file existence
using lib curl?

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.thekevindolan.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/15_19_1-Tree-Sunrise-Northumberland_web.jpg");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
    /* Do not do the transfer - only connect to host */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1L);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Answer (score 3):

CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT means that the TCP connection failed. You couldn't connect to that HTTP server on port 80 from the machine you ran that code!

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know what changes should i do to connect